# 'https' link is not loading in qwebview in qt creator

Tags: qt, https, openssl, qwebview, qt5.5

I am completely new to Qt and using Qt 5.5.1 version. I need to load an https link in my QWebview widget. But it is not loading. I tried with a different 'https' link address. Some will load, but some others will fail to get load. I googled the issue and found that it is due to an SSL error. If then how I am supposed to rectify this using OpenSSL. I am using Ubuntu 16. Can someone share any sample codes in Qt5.5.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use QNetworkAccessManager to ignore the SSL errors, something like this:

```
QNetworkAccessManager * nwAccessMgr = new QNetworkAccessManager();
QObject::connect
(
    nwAccessMgr, 
    &QNetworkAccessManager::sslErrors,
    [](QNetworkReply * reply, const QList<QSslError> & errors)
    {
        reply->ignoreSslErrors()
    }
);
view->page()->setNetworkAccessManager(nwAccessMgr);
```

PS: The added code snippet isn't compiled, so may have minor syntax errors.